# How do I email a parsed string from a spreadsheet each time a google form is submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a google form that requires users to select a name and ID from a list. The format of the name and ID can be either of two:

```
Smith, John (12345)
Doe, John (JDO)
```

I would like an email to be automatically sent to an address every time the form is submitted with a subject line that is the ID contained in the bracket only. I have the automatic email being sent and can get the entire string from the cell I want, but I need a function that can parse the string down to just what is contained in the brackets. This is what I have so far, pieced together from help I've found on this forum (thanks to amit@labnol.org).

```
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
  }

  function SendGoogleForm(e) 
  {  
  try 
  {  
    // You may also replace this with another email address
    var email = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";

    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails


    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var subject = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),21).getValue();
    var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order

    for(var i in headers) {
      message += headers[i] + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
    }

    message += "Sheet URL :: " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() + "\n";

    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp here.

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

 }
```

I'm only new to javascript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ID is contained within parentheses in both formats, you can use javascript string operations to isolate it efficiently:

```
...
var subject = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),21).getValue()
               .split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
...
```

Explanation: The [`split()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) breaks a string into an array of substrings. We first split on the open-parenthesis, which we expect will give us two substrings. We select the second (or 1-th, since array indexes start at 0) substring, which contains the ID, and further split it on the close-parenthesis. From that array, the first (0-th) element is our ID.